# ERROR: write /proc/414325/uid_map: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, namespaces

```
xx@xx:~$./userns -U -M '0 100000 65536' -G '0 100000 65535' bash
ERROR: write /proc/414325/uid_map: Operation not permitted
```

But use "./userns -U -M '0 100000 65536' -G '0 100000 1' bash " there not have error.why the length of range greater than 1 will occur error.

os: ubuntu
sources code of userns: [userns](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html#EXAMPLES)